# Weird beamer and xelatex math interaction

Tags: beamer, math-mode, xetex

I'm trying to use xelatex with beamer (I know, bad idea!) so that I can use a particular style file that I like. I'm running into some weird math display problems. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$ a < b \log n $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which yields the following:

[image]

So I think that I'll get rid of Asana-Math because maybe it has some font problems. The resulting image I get looks like this:

[image]

So either way I'm in a bind. Either basic characters are not recognized or I can't use operators (and this happens with \exp as well).

Is there something obvious that I'm missing ?

Comment: Add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` (and don't load `xltxtra`).

Comment: it didn't actually change anything (after making the changes you suggested).

Comment: This is the picture I get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6EJNr.png